# Reading header containing dates in Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet:

```
  31-12-2019  31-01-2020  28-02-2020 *(which btw is formatted as: 31-Dec-19, 31-Jan-20, etc. not sure if relevant)* 
1  -0,36%       0,12%      -0,09%
2  -0,18%       0,06%      -0,07%
3   0,05%       0,04%       0,14%
```

To be clear, the problem is not in reading the file, but the issue below.

I want to read this file with pandas in python and have the dates in the header as **strings**. So that later i can to refer to any column with something like df['31-12-2019'].

When I read the excel now, I get a keyerror message, because the formats of the dates in the header are changed. I read it like this now:

`curve = pd.read_excel("Monthly curves.xlsx", sheet_name = "swap", skiprows = 1, index_col = 0)`

I receive the error when selecting for instance column 31-12-2019: "Keyerror: '31-12-2019'. Any help would be much appreciated!

Also, the first column does not have a header, how can I name it myself as 'years'?

Comment: have you tried `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')`?

Comment: Read the excel, and check the output of `df.columns`. The columns have to be strings only.

Comment: Of course :) This however does not allow me to refer to my columns the way I described. The dataframe seems to have a different format (i.e. " 2019-12-31 00:00:00") for the headers and when I try to retrieve a column the error I receive when stating df["2019-12-31 00:00:00] is: "KeyError: ' 2019-12-31 00:00:00". And trust me, ive tried all variations to it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used this:

```
import pandas as pnd

file = 'excelfile.xlsx'
df = pnd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=0,index_col=0)
df.head()
```

I don't know about naming the headers though...

Comment: What format are your headers in? Because I did the same and I can't refer to any column this way. Thanks for answering btw!

Comment: I followed the same format as the ones in your example, 31-Dec-19, 31-Jan-20, etc...

Comment: What does the header in python look like though? Because that gets changed for me to " 2019-12-31 00:00:00" and then I can't refer to it. Want to change it to strings.

Comment: When I first did it, I used `pnd.read_excel(file)` only and the headers were as you described "2019-12-31 00:00:00", etc. But when I specified the sheet and index columns with `pnd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=0,index_col=0)` the headers became like "2019-12-31" only. It would help if I see how you're doing it.

Comment: I have it the same way, only also added the skiprow argument as the first row in the sheet is empty: `curve = pd.read_excel("Monthly Curves.xlsx", sheet_name = "swap", skiprows= 1, index_col = 0)`. Is this helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around my problem by reading the file as follows:

`curve = pd.read_excel("Monthly Curves.xlsx", sheet_name = "swap", index_col = 0, skiprows = 2, header = None)`

Then to select for instance the 91th column I used .loc (because .ix is deprecated), and I did that  in the following way:

`M12 = curve.loc[:, 91]`

Hope that helps others as well!