# Pandas dataframe with datetime column names behaves unexpected in QTableModel

Tags: python, pandas, qtablewidget, pyside6

I am trying to automate processing of old Excel files and import to database. Using pandas.read_excel() works well for some files, but for others there are some problems.

I tried to produce a MWE (below), but it doesn't behave exactly the same as pandas.read_excel() because manually creating a dataframe appears to work fine. It is the pd.read_excel() function that does something...I think?

The excel file I am using is just whatever data in an old .xls format file, where one of the values in the first row is a date.

After importing the excel file with `pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=4, header=None)` and setting correct column names with `df.columns = ["1", "2"...etc]` and dropping the empty "not a header row" with `df = df.drop([0], axis=0)`, the dataframe looks correct and `print(df.head())` reports **5** rows and 16 columns. But `len(df)` gives **6** rows. The empty header row was dropped but appears to remain somewhere. `df.reindex([x for x in range(len(df))])` doesn't appear to do anything, even if I change it to `len(df)-1`.

```
   labnr lokalnr     lokalnamn  vf  ...  farg     arrive provtagare  anm
1   1463    Y581       UTTERÅN NaN  ...   111 2019-04-03      UO/MN  NaN
2   1464    Y585        SALUÅN NaN  ...   176 2019-04-03      UO/MN  NaN
3   1465    Y577       UTTERÅN NaN  ...   117 2019-04-03      UO/MN  NaN
4   1466    Y586        SALUÅN NaN  ...   193 2019-04-03      UO/MN  NaN
5   1467    Y574  S.ANUNDSJÖÅN NaN  ...   180 2019-04-03      UO/MN  NaN

[5 rows x 16 columns]
Rows:  6
Cols:  16
```

After this I add some columns, drop some columns, copy the values from one column to another. Again, `print(df.head())` looks fine, except it reports the wrong number of rows, which after these operations have doubled and become **12**. Also, the columns appear to have switched places.

```
  labnr  countycd  placecd placename  ...     colour sampler samplenote    labnote
1   NaN       NaN    0.173         Y  ... 2019-04-01   UO/MN  7061960.0  1619870.0
2   NaN       NaN    0.155         Y  ... 2019-04-01   UO/MN  7052170.0  1667930.0
3   NaN       NaN    0.165         Y  ... 2019-04-01   UO/MN  7040050.0  1630250.0
4   NaN    0.0081    0.000         Y  ... 2019-04-01   UO/MN  7057610.0  1666990.0
5   NaN       NaN    0.082         Y  ... 2019-04-01   UO/MN  7053030.0  1587960.0

[5 rows x 20 columns]
Rows:  12
Cols:  20
```

The actual data looks somewhat fine except the columns jumped to new places. But when this is added to a QTableModel, the results are interesting. Header looks fine, but the index goes from 1..6 and then 0..5 for the second set of rows. Data values are jumbled, and the columns again switch place in the first and second set of rows. Nothing is correct in the QTableView except the header.

Since I depend on the QTableModel to allow editing of one or two numbers in each file imported this way, it is crucial for my application that the QTableView displays data correctly.

Could this be a problem with how old .xls files are read? How can I bypass this problem?

MWE that shows some operations I am doing, but it is producing a correct result, whereas reading the .xls does not produce correct results:

```
import pandas as pd

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex
import sys, datetime


class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    """A model to interface a Qt view with pandas dataframe """

    def __init__(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._dataframe = dataframe

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        """ Override method from QAbstractTableModel

        Return row count of the pandas DataFrame
        """
        if parent == QModelIndex():
            return len(self._dataframe)

        return 0

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        """Override method from QAbstractTableModel

        Return column count of the pandas DataFrame
        """
        if parent == QModelIndex():
            return len(self._dataframe.columns)
        return 0

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role=Qt.ItemDataRole):
        """Override method from QAbstractTableModel

        Return data cell from the pandas DataFrame
        """
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

        return None

    def headerData(
        self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: Qt.ItemDataRole
    ):
        """Override method from QAbstractTableModel

        Return dataframe index as vertical header data and columns as horizontal header data.
        """
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._dataframe.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._dataframe.index[section])

        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = {
      "Unnamed: 1": ["a", "b", 420, 380, 390],
      datetime.datetime(2019,4,3,0,0,0): ["x", "y", 50, 40, 45],
      "Unnamed: 2": ["g", "h", 51, 40, 45],
      "Unnamed: 3": ["d", "e", 52, 40, 45]
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df.columns)
    print(df.head())
    print("Rows: ", len(df))
    print("Cols: ", len(df.columns))
    # Should work with four column names?
    df.columns = ['Unnamed: 1', "daterenamed", 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3']
    df = df.drop([0, 1])
    newcol = ['nan' for x in range(len(df))]
    df.insert(1, column="new1", value=newcol)
    df = df.drop(df.columns[[1]], axis=1)
    df["new1"] = df["Unnamed: 1"]
    df.reindex([x for x in range(len(df))])
    print(df.head())
    print("Rows: ", len(df))
    print("Cols: ", len(df.columns))

    view = QTableView()
    view.resize(800, 500)
    view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)

    model = PandasModel(df)
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()
    app.exec()
```

[Reading header containing dates in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754194/reading-header-containing-dates-in-python-pandas)
This question deals with the same problem I think, but the suggested solutions of using headers=None, skiprows=3, index_col=0 they don't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Oopsie. The problem was not actually with the datetime.

After extensive review, I finally found a `df.append(columndata)` which is what caused the data to misalign (why doesn't this throw an error when the length of data is mismatch to row length?). After replacing it with `df["newcolname"] = columndata` the code works.

Something is still amiss. It is not possible to reindex the data, because the 0-index-row is hidden somewhere in there. But the code now works and I am able to continue storing the data.